# Allow daemon user SSH login keys

Tags: macos, hadoop, ssh

I'm setting up Hadoop on Mac OS X. I created a daemon user (no home directory, no set shell). Hadoop requires that the user be able to log in using SSH keys.

However, I do NOT want to create a home directory for the daemon user (that's messy). Nor do I want to enable the daemon user's shell.

How do I enable the daemon user to self-login via SSH without a home directory?

Comment: @Xeli Thanks, I did a search but didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, every user account needs to have a home directory.  It does not need to be unique.  Mac OS X 10.9, for example, uses /var/empty for many of its user accounts.

Likewise, Mac OS X uses /usr/bin/false as the shell for those daemons.  They are not able to log in, but they can be set to using setuid(2) by another program which has SUID privileges.

The foregoing doesn't solve your SSH question, admittedly.  The link provided by Xeli in a comment should give you some ideas about how to configure your SSH server to work.